# How to Add Line Breaks/ Titles between groups of values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add titles or breaks between groups of names in MYSQL. Here's an example.

Output:

```
Bob     Honda        1
Bob     Acura        2
Bob     Toyota       3
Joe     Honda        1
Joe     Acura        2
Joe     Toyota       3
Jim     Honda        1
Jim     Acura        2
Jim     Toyota       3
```

What I want is:

```
Bob
Bob     Honda        1
Bob     Acura        2
Bob     Toyota       3
Joe
Joe     Honda        1
Joe     Acura        2
Joe     Toyota       3
Jim
Jim     Honda        1
Jim     Acura        2
Jim     Toyota       3
```

or even just this

```
Bob     Honda        1
Bob     Acura        2
Bob     Toyota       3

Joe     Honda        1
Joe     Acura        2
Joe     Toyota       3

Jim     Honda        1
Jim     Acura        2
Jim     Toyota       3
```

Is this possible through MySQL?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Fix it in an above layer (php or whatever.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply jarlh. Do you know if this would be possible through JQuery? If so, does anyone know how I might be able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose initially you have a query like this

```
select name, 
       car, 
       number
from a_table
```

You can use something like this

```
select name, 
       car, 
       number
from a_table
union all
select name, 
       '' as car, 
       1000000000  as number
from a_table
group by name
order by name, number
```

here grouped results generates the extra lines and then `order by` fixes the rows orders.